# JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId. on Android studio

Tags: android

When i build apk in Android studio project finished successfully but i see this error in event log.
How can i solve it??

```
JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, after updating to the latest version of android studio, that is version 1.5.1.
My problem is solved by modifying the path of gradle in preferences, figure

[image: [1]], and by changing its version on build.gradle of my project, figure

[image: [2]].

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by 'Clean Project'