# Android Studio - required between publicId and systemId?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

I have below error :

> Gradle sync failed: White spaces are required between publicId and
>   systemId.
>                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

What can I do ?

Comment: Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184654/jdomparseexception-error-on-line-1-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid

Comment: How can i give you a point ? Thanks a lot .

Comment: I put an answer, you can validate it :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by modifying the path of gradle in preferences and by changing its version on build.gradle.

Check this question : [JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId. on Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184654/jdomparseexception-error-on-line-1-white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid)